# Print error with print step, sess.run(w), sess.run(b)

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://gist.github.com/tomonari-masada/ed2fbc94a9f6252036eea507b7119045

I tried to run the above code in JupyterLab Notebook, but error in printing:
print step, sess.run(w), sess.run(b).

Please help and advise.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in many ways
One). consider optimization problems.
Two). session variables.

Using model fit or evaluation method they create local steps and global steps but simply using for local variable optimizes you can use the global steps or records as history, At this point the step training may not indicate the real truth because you perform individual function then global steps overwrites the rules.

Sample 1: Optimizers problems.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
learning_rate = 0.001
global_step = 0
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

history = [ ] 
history_Y = [ ]

scale = 1.0
sigma = 1.0
min_size = 1.0

# logdir = 'F:\\models\\log'
# savedir = 'F:\\models\\save'

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Function
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, num_add):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.num_add = num_add
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.add( inputs, self.num_add )
        temp = tf.matmul(temp, self.kernel)
        return temp

#####################################################################################################

class SeqmentationOptimization(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SeqmentationOptimization, self).__init__()
        scale_init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=10, maxval=1000, seed=None)
        sigma_init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0.001, maxval=1, seed=None)
        min_size_init = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=10, maxval=1000, seed=None)

        self.scale = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = scale_init,
                                trainable=True)
        self.sigma = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = sigma_init,
                                trainable=True)
        
        self.min_size = self.add_weight(shape=[1],
                                initializer = min_size_init,
                                trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        objects = Segmentation(self.scale , self.sigma , self.min_size ).objects
        return 
        

class Segmentation( ):
    def __init__( self, scale , sigma , min_size ):
        
        print( 'start __init__: ' )
        self.scale = scale
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.min_size = min_size
        
        scale = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('scale', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        sigma = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('sigma', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        min_size = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('min_size', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
        
        Z = tf.nn.l2_loss( ( scale - sigma ) +( scale - min_size ) , name="loss")
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
        
        optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
        learning_rate,
        initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
        l1_regularization_strength=0.2,
        l2_regularization_strength=0.1,
        use_locking=False,
        name='ProximalAdagrad'
        )
        training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
        
        self.loss = loss
        self.scale = scale
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.min_size = min_size
        self.training_op = training_op
        
        return 
    
    def create_loss_fn( self ):
        print( 'start create_loss_fn: ' )
        
        return self.loss, self.scale, self.sigma, self.min_size, self.training_op
    

X = np.reshape([ 500, -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, 1 ], (1, 10, 1))
Y = np.reshape([ -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))
Z = np.reshape([ -100, 200, -300, 300, -400, 400, -500, 500, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))


loss_segmentation = Segmentation( scale , sigma , min_size )
loss, scale, sigma, min_size, training_op = loss_segmentation.create_loss_fn( )
    
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1

        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={scale:X, sigma:Y, min_size:Z})
        history.append(train_loss)
        history_Y.append( history[0] - train_loss )
        
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        
sess.close()

plt.plot(np.asarray(history))
plt.plot(np.asarray(history_Y))
plt.show()
plt.close()

input('...')
```

Sample 2: Optimize variables

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
learning_rate = 0.001
global_step = 0
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

start = 3
limit = 33
delta = 3.0
inputs = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=0)
inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=0)
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
print(output)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate,
    initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
    l1_regularization_strength=0.2,
    l2_regularization_strength=0.1,
    use_locking=False,
    name='ProximalAdagrad'
)

var1 = tf.Variable(10.0)
var2 = tf.Variable(10.0)
X_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
y_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Y', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 10, 1)))
Z = tf.nn.l2_loss((var1 - X_var) ** 2 + (var2 - y_var) ** 2, name="loss")

cosine_loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
training_op = optimizer.minimize(cosine_loss(X_var, y_var))

X = np.reshape([ 500, -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, 1 ], (1, 10, 1))
Y = np.reshape([ -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X, y_var:Y})
        print( 'train_loss: ' + str( train_loss ) )
        
        with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("dekdee", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):

            print( X_var.eval() )

sess.close()

input('...')
```